# Python, pymysql class encapsulation of SSCursor not working as expected

Tags: python, class, pymysql

The following works:

```
class DB():
    def __init__(self, host, user, password, db):
        self.conn =  pymysql.connect(
            host = host,
            user = user,
            passwd = password,
            charset = 'utf8',
            cursorclass = pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,
            db = db
        )

        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

    def execute(self, sql):
        self.cur.execute(sql)

    def fetchone(self):
        return self.cur.fetchone()

cf = DB("localhost", "user", "pass", "db")
cf.execute("SELECT Count(*) FROM Table")
aryRes = cf.fetchone()
```

But when I replace the DictCursor with an SSCursor, aryRes contains None, and I get:

```
warnings.warn("Previous unbuffered result was left incomplete")
```

I've tried all the combinations of:

```
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors
from pymysql import cursors
```

I've also confirmed that the following returns correctly (Not encapsulated):

```
con = pymysql.connect(
    host = "localhost", 
    user = "user",
    passwd = "pass",
    charset = 'utf8',
    cursorclass = pymysql.cursors.SSCursor,
    db = "db"
)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT Count(*) FROM Table")
aryRes = cur.fetchone()
```

What am I missing that will make encapsulated SSCursors work?
I'm new to Python, so feel free to correct anything you feel needs attention.

***Forgot to mention... I'm using Python 2.7.12***

Comment: I cannot recreate any issue. No warning and no empty `aryRes`. Do note: the password argument in `pymysql.connect` is **passwd**.

Comment: Nice catch! I'll fix it now. I changed my code here as well, but it didn't affect my situation - probably because my db password is empty.

Comment: I wanted to reassure myself... You did change the DictCursor to SSCursor in the top example, right?

Comment: Both cursor classes worked for me for top and bottom examples.

Comment: I left one thing out of my sample code. After self.cursor.execute(), I had self.conn.commit(), which fails for SELECT queries.

Comment: I thought `SScursor` doesn't need `conn.commit()`. I have problem like this. it disappear when I remove `conn.commit()` after `cursor.execute()`

Answer (score 1):

I think You have problem because You fetch just one result, while there are others. After `fetchone`, try running `fetchall` to clear buffer.

Comment: Well, it's worth a shot, but a couple of things come to mind... 1) I don't need to fetchall() in the non-encapsulated version, and 2) the query itself is written to return one record.

Comment: Ok I tried it, and instead of returning None, it returned an empty array, and the error message persisted.